# Java calculation problems

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, loops, for-loop

Long question here, just a disclaimer.

I'm trying to code an average score "calculator" with Eclipse. It's a university assignment and the "scenario" is a fictional winter olympics event, focusing on snowboarding. Each athlete has 2 runs, with 7 judges each giving a score out of 10. 
I'm using Eclipse with WindowBuilder to build the GUI. Scores are entered into 7 individual textfields named txtRun1_0; txtRun1_1; txtRun1_2; etc. through to txtRun1_6. As seen in the code below, I am storing the strings in an array, and then parsing each string to a double in another equally sized array for doubles. Then I continue with the calculation.

The confusing part is that the code below is simply adapted to work with a GUI; I originally wrote it to work with the console, and it works perfectly. I will include the original code as well. As you will see, the main calculation parts of the code are nearly identical, apart from a couple of very slight changes in variable names.

**EDIT: The problem with the program is this: If I enter 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, and 7 as the scores, it returns the average of the scores as 0.0, and the highest AND lowest of the scores is 7.0.**

The program has to adhere to the following criteria:

- Highest and lowest scores are truncated from the calculation
- Arrays are a must

I've double checked and triple checked the names for all my labels and variables, but I haven't found anything wrong with it.

Here is my code for the GUI program (for run 1):

```
            //Start Variables Declaration
            double [] daRun1 = new double[7]; //Run1 Array
            double [] daRun2 = new double[7]; //Run2 Array
            String [] saRun1 = new String[7]; //Run1 String Array
            String [] saRun2 = new String[7]; //Run2 String Array
            int di1; //daRun1 index integer
            int di2; //daRun2 index integer
            int si1; //saRun1 index integer
            int si2; //saRun2 index integer

            //End Variables Declaration

            ///////////////
            //Run 1 Start//
            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            //Get values from JTextFields (txtRun1_0 to txtRun1_6)//
            //and enter them in to their respective arrays//////////
            //Run 1 Scores//////////////////////////////////
            ///////////////
            saRun1[0] = txtRun1_0.getText();
            saRun1[1] = txtRun1_1.getText();
            saRun1[2] = txtRun1_2.getText();
            saRun1[3] = txtRun1_3.getText();
            saRun1[4] = txtRun1_4.getText();
            saRun1[5] = txtRun1_5.getText();
            saRun1[6] = txtRun1_6.getText();

            //Parses string values of saRun1 to integers
            //and enters them into daRun1 (array of doubles)
            //to make calculation of average scores possible
            for (di1=0; di1<daRun1.length; di1++)
            {
                for (si1=0; si1<saRun1.length; si1++)
                {
                    daRun1[di1] = Double.parseDouble(saRun1[si1]);
                }
            }

            //Finds the maximum and minimum scores
            //for Run 1, ready for truncating them during
            //average score calculation
            double min1 = daRun1[0];
            double max1 = daRun1[0];

            for (di1=0; di1<daRun1.length; di1++)
            {
                if (daRun1[di1] > max1)
                    {max1 = daRun1[di1];}

                if (daRun1[di1] < min1)
                    {min1 = daRun1[di1];}
            }

                //These println statements are there to help me debug the code; the result of the calculation is allocated to a label further down in the code.
                System.out.println("The maximum score for Run 1 is: " + max1 + "\nThe minimum score for Run 1 is: " + min1); 

            //Calculates the average score 
            //for Run 1 (not including the maximum and minimum scores)
            double sum1 = 0.0;
            double avg1 = 0.0;

            for (di1=0 ; di1<daRun1.length ; di1++)
            {
                if(daRun1[di1] == max1 || daRun1[di1] == min1)
                    continue;
                sum1 += daRun1[di1];
            }
            avg1 = sum1 / (daRun1.length-2);


            //Output to lblAvgRun1
            lblAvgRun1.setText(Double.toString(avg1));
            System.out.println(avg1);
```

And here is my code for the console version:

```
    double [] daRun1 = new double[7]; //Run1 Array
    double [] daRun2 = new double[7]; //Run2 Array
    int i1; //daRun1 index integer
    int i2; //daRun2 index integer


    //Initializes console input
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));


    ////////////////
    //Run 1 Start///
    ////////////////

    System.out.println("Enter the 7 scores for run 1:");

    //Run 1 Data Entry below
    for (i1=0; i1<daRun1.length; i1++)
    {
        daRun1[i1] = Double.parseDouble(br.readLine());
    }

    //Printing Array Elements - Run 1
    for (i1=0; i1<daRun1.length; i1++)
    {
        System.out.println(i1+1 + " " + daRun1[i1]);
    }

    //Find maximum and minimum scores - Run 1
    double min1 = daRun1[0];
    double max1 = daRun1[0];

    for (i1=0; i1<daRun1.length; i1++)
    {
        if (daRun1[i1] > max1)
            {max1 = daRun1[i1];}

        if (daRun1[i1] < min1)
            {min1 = daRun1[i1];}
    }
    System.out.println("The maximum score for Run 1 is: " + max1 + "\nThe minimum score for Run 1 is: " + min1);

    //Calculate the average score - Run 1
    double sum1 = 0.0;
    double avg1 = 0.0;

    for (i1=0 ; i1<daRun1.length ; i1++)
    {
        if(daRun1[i1] == max1 || daRun1[i1] == min1)
            continue;
        sum1 += daRun1[i1];
    }
    avg1 = sum1 / (daRun1.length-2);

    System.out.println("The average score for Run 1 is: " + avg1);
    //End Run 1//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Comment: So what is exactly your question?

Comment: You're right I completely forgot to write out the issue. Edited the OP.

Comment: Please explain what's the problem is in one sentence. For example'The GUI version seems to not truncated Highest and lowest scores'. Now I'm not sure what we are looking for.

Comment: Side note on cod quality: read about about java coding styleguides; and adhere to them. For example: use consistent formatting for your braces (hint: just use the built-in code formatter of eclipse, ctrl-f is your friend). Then: don't try to be "funny" in code (like "daRun"). Code should not be "funny", it should be easy to read, and for example: do only ONE thing per method. Not 2, not 5, or 20, like in your code.

Comment: @Jägermeister the daRun is not to be funny, the d is for double, a is for array, and Run1 is the name of the array. It's how we're being told to name our variables and arrays. 
About doing one thing per method, I'm not quite sure what you mean. This all has to work with one button press in the GUI program.

Comment: @Jägermeister the code is fine...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing:

```
for (si1=0; si1<saRun1.length; si1++)
{
    daRun1[di1] = Double.parseDouble(saRun1[si1]);
}
```

To:

```
for (si1=0; si1<saRun1.length; si1++)
{
    daRun1[si1] = Double.parseDouble(saRun1[si1]);
}
```

You are just overwriting the same array element every time you loop through...

Also I'm not sure why you have the outer loop there because it is not a multi-dimensional array. The inner loop should be enough...

Comment: Thanks! I think that's done it! 
This should also mean that I can remove the first part of that nested loop, right?

Comment: @RThomP just use the loop from above.

Comment: CONFIRMED. This is the correct solution. Thank you again @brso05

Comment: @RThomP no problem! Glad I could help!